# Getting credentials for google drive for server application

Tags: google-drive-api

I am looking for a decent example or an explanation of how to get google drive credentials without having to authenticate through a browser.

What I am trying to accomplish is having a server upload photos to google drive after extracting information from them. Currently I understand how to interact with the api to accomplish this but I am having trouble understanding the OAuth2 process google requires to gain access to the drive.

I would like the server to authenticate itself without user input upon start up.

Currently from this page
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2

It appears that I would need to use the installed application example to get the credentials. There are two problems that I am having trouble overcoming

1) I cannot find the correct libraries to implement the functions required despite having downloaded both the drive libraries and the OAuth2 libraries.

2) The installed application code requires a user to authenticate through a browser. I do not want a user to have to authenticate I would prefer the server does this automatically.

Any information or code examples on implementing this functionality would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. Set up your account for [2-step verification](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180744&topic=1099588&ctx=topic).
2. Set up an [application specific password](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833).